# gitlab new directory is created under main directory?

Tags: gitlab

**Note: I want to use only GitLab web UI.**

In gitlab I want to create an empty folder under A/B but when I go inside B, click on + and then New Directory it creates one directly Under A.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must write the whole path (recursive) from root folder in the field *Directory name*. In youf example `A/B` if you want to create a new directory `B`in a already existing `A`-directory.

[image]

Fore more information, look at this [article](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/02/10/feature-highlight-create-files-and-directories-from-files-page/) about "Create files and directories from the Files page"

Comment: Does it work with my solution?